# Building with Boost.Python and static libraries

Tags: c++, python, boost, compilation, compiler-errors

I want to make a C++ application that can handle python plugins, so i'm getting into boost.python. I'm creating some test programs that I build with CMake.

In my test program, I have a simple "library" that propose a plugin interface (using boost.python to expose this to python), and a plugin loader (not coded yet, nothing inside).

When I try to build my executable directly (without any libraries), I get a link error (module I've exposed is called pythonPlugin) :

```
duplicate symbol _initpythonPlugin in:
    CMakeFiles/pythonPluginer.dir/main.cpp.o
    libcoreLib.a(PluginLoader.cpp.o)
duplicate symbol __Z24init_module_pythonPluginv in:
    CMakeFiles/pythonPluginer.dir/main.cpp.o
    libcoreLib.a(PluginLoader.cpp.o)
```

I have the same result when I build an intermediate static library. However, when I turn this library into a shared one, this works fine. Here is a sub CMakeList.txt :

```
file(GLOB sources core/*.h core/*.cpp )

add_library(coreLib SHARED ${sources})
target_link_libraries(coreLib 
                      ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} 
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(pythonPluginer main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pythonPluginer 
                      coreLib)
```

Do you have any explanation to this ? Is it possible to make a program with boost/python without using shared libraries ?

Thanks,
Denis.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and remove core/*.h from the file(GLOB...) command
Header files need not be compiled and this might actually cause the problem of the duplicate symbols.